# Using Highcharts areasplinerange with multiple series

Tags: javascript, html, css, highcharts

I'm looking to use Highcharts to create an analog for a [stream graph](http://www.visualisingdata.com/2010/08/making-sense-of-streamgraphs/). With these, the y-axis isn't indicative of the value, but instead the size of the area at a particular point is. I decided to use the "areasplinerange" to plot each of these series and it seems to work quite well. However, I'm running into an issue where the on hover events don't seem to behave properly. If you hover over the biggest bubble (Brand 42), and move your cursor up and down (still within the area), you'll notice a flicker on the hovered series. These series are designed to not overlap so when you hover over one of them, it should stay highlighted. I'm not sure whether this is a bug or if there is some parameter that I'm not using to get this to work. Any help is much appreciated.

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/h1haxbep/9/) an example fiddle and the relevant chartConfig settings.

```
var allBrands = [
  "Brand 1",
  "Brand 2",
  "Brand 3",
  "Brand 4",
  "Brand 5",
  "Brand 6",
  "Brand 7",
  "Brand 8",
  "Brand 9",
  "Brand 10",
  "Brand 11",
  "Brand 12",
  "Brand 13",
  "Brand 14",
  "Brand 15",
  "Brand 16",
  "Brand 17",
  "Brand 18",
  "Brand 19",
  "Brand 20",
  "Brand 21",
  "Brand 22",
  "Brand 23",
  "Brand 24",
  "Brand 25",
  "Brand 26",
  "Brand 27",
  "Brand 28",
  "Brand 29",
  "Brand 30",
  "Brand 31",
  "Brand 32",
  "Brand 33",
  "Brand 34",
  "Brand 35",
  "Brand 36",
  "Brand 37",
  "Brand 38",
  "Brand 39",
  "Brand 40",
  "Brand 41",
  "Brand 42",
  "Brand 43",
  "Brand 44",
  "Brand 45",
  "Brand 46",
  "Brand 47",
  "Brand 48",
  "Brand 49",
  "Brand 50",
  "Brand 51",
  "Brand 52",
  "Brand 53",
  "Brand 54",
  "Brand 55",
  "Brand 56"
]

var months = [{
  "date": "2015-07-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {

  }
}, {
  "date": "2015-08-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 32": 119.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2015-09-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 7": 29.99,
    "Brand 23": 49.99,
    "Brand 52": 49.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2015-10-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 1": 109.98,
    "Brand 6": 39.98,
    "Brand 12": 84.98,
    "Brand 18": 79.99,
    "Brand 19": 59.99,
    "Brand 22": 39.99,
    "Brand 27": 69.99,
    "Brand 28": 75.98,
    "Brand 34": 29.99119,
    "Brand 42": 3199.98,
    "Brand 51": 129.98,
    "Brand 56": 69.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2015-11-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {

  }
}, {
  "date": "2015-12-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 3": 109.99,
    "Brand 10": 459.97,
    "Brand 11": 34.99,
    "Brand 17": 89.99,
    "Brand 18": 119.97999999999999,
    "Brand 29": 183.99,
    "Brand 30": 99.99,
    "Brand 35": 82.98,
    "Brand 38": 44.99,
    "Brand 40": 24.99,
    "Brand 41": 279.98,
    "Brand 47": 59.991199,
    "Brand 55": 49.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 4": 59.99,
    "Brand 8": 49.99,
    "Brand 14": 149.99,
    "Brand 16": 139.99,
    "Brand 21": 199.98,
    "Brand 25": 89.98,
    "Brand 26": 44.99,
    "Brand 31": 259.98,
    "Brand 38": 49.99,
    "Brand 43": 198,
    "Brand 45": 39.99469,
    "Brand 46": 19.99,
    "Brand 47": 49.99,
    "Brand 53": 89.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 9": 49.99,
    "Brand 13": 219.98,
    "Brand 39": 89.99,
    "Brand 44": 184.98000000000002,
    "Brand 50": 99.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 2": 89.99,
    "Brand 4": 109.98,
    "Brand 5": 29.99,
    "Brand 10": 139.99,
    "Brand 20": 35.99,
    "Brand 26": 79.99,
    "Brand 33": 39.99,
    "Brand 48": 59.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2016-04-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {

  }
}, {
  "date": "2016-05-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {
    "Brand 7": 59.99,
    "Brand 15": 59.99,
    "Brand 17": 94.99,
    "Brand 24": 39.98,
    "Brand 25": 39.99619,
    "Brand 29": 279.98,
    "Brand 30": 149.99,
    "Brand 36": 99.99,
    "Brand 37": 39.99,
    "Brand 38": 34.99,
    "Brand 49": 59.99,
    "Brand 54": 49.99
  }
}, {
  "date": "2016-06-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "brands": {

  }
}]


var seriesMap = {};

for (var i = 0; i < months.length; i++) {
  var month = months[i];
  var total = 0;
  for (var name in month.brands) {
    if (month.brands.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      total += month.brands[name] || 0;
    }
  }

  var y = 0 - (total / 2);
  for (var j = 0; j < allBrands.length; j++) {
    var brand = allBrands[j];
    var series = seriesMap[brand];
    if (!series) {
      var series = {
        name: brand,
        data: []
      };
      seriesMap[brand] = series;
    }
    var value = month.brands[brand] || 0;
    series.data.push([new Date(month.date).getTime(), y, y + value]);
    y += value;
  }
}
window.seriesMap = seriesMap;

var seriesArray = [];
var keys = Object.keys(seriesMap).sort();
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  seriesArray.push(seriesMap[keys[i]]);
}

window.seriesArray = seriesArray;

$('#container').highcharts({

  chart: {
    type: 'areasplinerange'
  },

  title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Streamgraph'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  yAxis: {
    visible: false,
    labels: {
      enabled: false
    }
  },
  colors: ["#0e658d", "#cceaf8", "#0095da", "#66bfe9"],
  plotOptions: {
    stickyTracking: true,
    trackByArea: false,
    stacking: true,
    series: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function(event) {
          this.options.oldColor = this.color;
          this.update({
            "color": "#ff9600"
          });
        },
        mouseOut: function(event) {
          this.update({
            "color": this.options.oldColor
          });
        }
      },
      fillOpacity: 1
    }
  },

  tooltip: {
    formatter: function() {
      return this.series.name + " $" + (this.point.high - this.point.low).toFixed(2).toLocaleString();
    }
  },

  legend: {
    enabled: false
  },
  series: seriesArray

});
```

Thanks!

Comment: In Highcharts, tooltip activity is triggered by the cursor's proximity to the x values of the series. So even if you're within the area of one series, if the mouse moves closer to an x value from another series, that response will be triggered. Possible solutions are custom mouseover/out events, possibly something in the tooltip config settings?

Comment: Hmm thanks that's a good idea. I'll fiddle around with custom mouseover events to see what I can do.

Comment: Nice work, btw. I wanted to try building a stream graph in HIghcharts, but never got around to figuring out how to process the data properly.

Comment: Really nice chart :) I think that you can use jQuery mouseover and mouseout for changing color of paths, that are making your series. Here you can see an example how it can work: http://jsfiddle.net/h1haxbep/10/

Comment: Thanks guys. Grzegorz, I ultimately did end up using pure jQuery to bind mousemove on the entire chart, and then did some math to figure out where the mouse was hovering and whether it was on top of one of the series.

Also, I did have to disable the tooltip cause it will still have the old behavior of occasionally displaying data over the wrong series. To remedy this, I declare the function to handle the tooltip after I have determined which series is the correct one.

chart.tooltip.options.formatter = formatTooltip;